# Collect data by id in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I have a table with rows in following format

```
user |  purchase | time_of_purchase|quantity
```

Sample

```
1234 | Bread | Jul 7 20:48| 1
1234 | Shaving Cream | July 10 14:20 | 2
5678 | Milk | July 7 3:48 | 1 
5678 | Bread | July 7 3:49 | 2
5678 | Bread | July 7 15:30 | 1
```

I want to create purchase history of the user in following format

```
1234 | {[Bread , Jul 7 20:48,1] ,[ Shaving Cream , July 10 14:20, 2 ]}
5678 | {[Milk, July 7 3:48 , 1 ] , [Bread , July 7 3:49 , 2], [Bread , July 7 15:30 , 1]}
```

Is it possible to do this in hive or pig script? I tried collect_list but that does not keep order across columns to combine , Also tried brickhouse collect but that behaves like collect_set and I lose part of the information.

Comment: It looks possible using Spark because it's a `groupByKey` operation

Comment: You can use select * from table name groupby id query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PIG Script**

```
File = LOAD 'file.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (user:int, Purchase:chararray,  timeofpurchase:chararray, quantity:int); 

GRP_USER = GROUP File by user;
DUMP GRP_USER;
```

you can refer few example on http://ybhavesh.blogspot.com/

**Hope it Helps**